# Free U2 album doesn't show up in artist folder under U2

Tags: itunes

The album is instead in my iTunes artist list filed under 'G'?! So my artist list looks like this: Green Day, U2, David Guetta. I do have a song by Green Day and U2 which also appears here but don't know why Songs of Innocence isn't filed under U2 with the other albums of theirs. What is going on and how do I fix it, please?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Songs list, sort by Artist & see if the same happens; then shift/select the entire album tracklist, hit  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>  +  <kbd>I</kbd>  & make sure both Artist & Album Artist say U2.

[image]